# Laravel option route parameter not working

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm using laravel 5.2 and having problems with regards to routing. Supposed I have this route: `http://example.com/out/parameter1/parameter2/`

**Parameter1** should be required while **Parameter2** should be optional. When user enter this url: `http://example.com/out/parameter1/` or this `http://example.com/out/parameter1/parameter2/`, they should be able to proceed. By when this is entered, `http://example.com/out/` they will be redirected to the homepage.

Here's my route:

```
Route::get('out/{param1}/{param2?}', 'MyController@out']);
Route::get('out/', 'MyController@redirect']);
```

The controller:

```
public function out($param1, $param2 = '', Request $request) {
    // logic here
}
```

The error that I'm getting is this:
`Argument 3 passed to App\Http\Controllers\MyController::out() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given`

I already specify a default value for `param2` on the method.

Comment: check with your router. change Route::get('out/{param1}/{param2?}', 'MyController@out']); to Route::get('out/{param1}/{param2}', 'MyController@out']);

Comment: @MansoorH, it is not working as I am getting a 404 error. Also, `param2` should be optional.

Comment: What can be the possible values of third parameter can you please define

Comment: change it, public function out($param1, $param2 = null, Request $request) { }

Comment: @Uchiha, `param2` could be anything.

Comment: @MansoorH, still gives me the same error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request instance must be the first one

```
public function out(Request $request, $param1, $param2 = '') 
{
    // logic here
}
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers under Method Injection

Comment: this worked!!!! Thanks!! I'm still unable to accept this as the correct answer as it requires me a couple of minutes. I'll be marking this in a while :)